# How to run this module from this path?

Tags: python, module

I have the following file structure:

```
Project
|
├───cambridge_loader
|   |
│   ├───tests
│   │
│   ├───__init__.py
│   │
│   ├───__main__.py
│   │
│   ├───CambridgeLoader.py
```

I'm in the `Project` directory on my command line, I created a virtual environment in Visual Stdio and executed the `activate.bat` script.

I've tried running:

`python -m CambridgeLoader`

And get the following error:

`C:\Users\username\Source\Repos\rapdataload\Frauenfeld\env\Scripts\python.exe: No module named CambridgeLoader`

I've tried running it in different paths but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure why it's attaching the Scripts path at the end...

Comment: Your module's name is `cambridge_loader`.

Comment: Jesus christ, for some reason I assumed it was the name of the Class...Thank you

Comment: No problem, easy mistake!